# How to calculate amount of contingency tables?

Tags: math, statistics

If i want to calculate the amount of k-dimensional contingency tables which formula should I use?

For example, if i have 16 categorical variables in my dataset and want to calculate the amount of 1-dimensional contingency tables, then it's clear, there is only 1 table. If I want to calculate the amount of 2-dimensional contingency tables then I assume there are 120. But how do I calculate it? And what if i have much more variables and k-dimensional tables?

I'm searching for one equations with gives me the number of available contingency tables, given the dimension (k) and the number of variables (n).

Comment: Your question does not make any sense. Please explain some of the terms you are using. For e.g. What is a contingency table? Some examples of what you need will help understand it better.

Comment: what exactly makes no sense? i think for people who are working with this stuff it should be clear.

Comment: Like one of the posters who seems well versed in the subject matter asked: What is a k-dimensional contingency table? Anyway, I apologize. I didn't mean to offend you. Just that having a clearly phrased question will help you solve your problem quickly. Also, my fault. I didn't see the statistic tag.

Comment: No problem. I understand that its maybe a little bit unclear, but thats also because i'm not a native english speaker. I was just curious about asking what a contingency table is, because i wouldn't ask in a java question what a JButton is ;) But as you said I'm happy that you could help that fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For moron - a contingency table is defined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table).

Sebi - I think you do need to clarify the problem a bit, but let me plow ahead.  If I had 16 categorical variables and need to define a contingency table for each pair of variables, that would be C(16,2) = 120 tables.  (Combinations of 16 choose 2). Is that what you mean by k-dimension tables?

If so, the number of k dimension tables is simply C(16,k).  The excel function is Combin(n,k).

C(16,3) =  560
C(16,4) = 1820
C(16,5) = 4368
C(16,6) = 8008... and so on....

Comment: nice this is what i need. will vote up as soon as i have votes again ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you are trying to select distinct subsets of size k from the n variables, I suspect the formula will be:
number of tables =  n! / ( (n-k)! k!)